# DB2 for i: non-UDF macro functions? (User Defined Functions are slow, but complicated formulas are complicated)

Tags: function, macros, db2

I have complicated but fairly consistent formulas I need to execute.

When done on large tables, UDFs are incredibly slow, so I'd rather avoid them (execution time with a UDF in the SELECT clause is 30-100x slower than with an equivalent in-line statement, on larger tables)

I can write in-line formulas instead, but the resultant code is huge, unreadable, and much harder to maintain.

Is there a way to design something like C or SAS macros, which just do straight-up text replacement within the query?

I want something like the following

given:

`isKeyValid(key, param1, param2)`

generated code: (this is just random nonsense I wrote on the fly - it should support any quantity of raw SQL)

```
    case 
    when param1 in ('a','b','c') and substr(param2,1,2) = '53' and key=param1||param2 then 1
    when param1 in ('a','d','e') and substr(param2,1,2) = '51' and key=param1||param2 then 1
    else 0 
    end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never seen any issue with UDFs on the i...

What version and release are you on?  Assuming a current version (v7.2 or higher) take a look at the enhancements to UDF inlining [added in 2016](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/node/1116615), to ensure your code can be inlined.

[Inlining support for User Defined Table Functions (UDTFs)](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/node/1168192)
[Improved Inlining support for SQL Scalar User Defined Functions (UDFs)](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/node/1168180)

> Inline functions: When an SQL scalar function is inlined, instead of
> invoking the function as part of a query, the expression in the RETURN
> statement of the function may be copied (inlined) into the query
> itself. Such a function is called an inline function. A scalar
> function is an inline function if:
>
> - The SQL function is global deterministic.
> - ***The SQL-routine-body contains only a RETURN statement.***
> - No input parameter is an array type.
> - The data type of the result is not XML or an array type.
> - All objects referenced in the function exist when the function is    created.
> - The SQL-routine-body does not contain a common table expression that references an input parameter.
> - The SQL-routine-body does not contain a nested table expression without a preceding    LATERAL keyword that references an input
>   parameter.
>
> An inline function is only copied (inlined) into a query if:
>
> - The query is eligible for the SQL Query Engine (SQE).
> - The function references an object and the authority attributes of the function and the query are compatible based on one of the
>   following conditions:
>
>   - The function is defined to run under the user's authority (*USER).
>   - The query is running under the owner's authority (*OWNER) and the owner of the query is the same as the owner of the function.
>   - The query is running under the user's authority (*USER), and the user or the user's group profile is the same as the owner of the
>     function.
>
> Note: If the function is defined as FENCED, the query must not use
> adopted authority. If the query runs under the owner's authority
> (*OWNER) and the function runs under the user’s authority (*USER), the
> owner of the query must be the same as the user or the user's group
> profile.

In particular, pay attention to the highlighted requirement that the function contain just a `RETURN`.  If you have a compound statement using `BEGIN` and `END`; your function won't be inlined.